# when images are dragged onto my desktop screen the show a link and not the actual image

Tags: unity

I just started with Ubuntu. At first if i dragged and dropped an image to my desktop it would create a link, if I would grab that link and place it elsewhere in the desktop it would give me the actual image, it was kinda annoying but it was ok. Now recently when i try to drag the image the second time it wont give me the image, itll just move the link. Can i just drag & drop the actual image into the desktop?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. What you could do is to make desktop a default folder for saving stuff, and when you right click on the image and select 'Save Image' , it'll go to desktop. Let me know if you want me to post it as an actual answer